# How does Haskell's type system generate this error?

Tags: haskell

In my ventures through Haskell, I find that when I make a mistake with types in my code, I have a tough time trying to parse what it is that I did wrong and the compiler is complaining about. I think this is because of partial type inference before the compiler finds something wrong.

Of course, I'm used to languages where the type mismatches are very obvious. e.g. something along the lines of `function foo expects an argument of type int, but received string`. It's obvious what this means, I passed in a string but the signature demands an int.

So here's some relatively simple code, it is a function that evaluates a polynomial given a list of coefficients and powers:

```hs
poly :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Double -> Double
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
```

This produces the following compiler error output:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( solution.hs, solution.o )

solution.hs:11:56: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Double’
      Expected type: [Double] -> [(Double, Double)]
        Actual type: [Double] -> [(Int, Double)]
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘zip a’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘map (\ (ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a’
      In the expression: sum . map (\ (ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a
   |
11 | poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
   |                                                        ^^^^^

solution.hs:11:64: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Double’
      Expected type: [Double]
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘b’
      In the expression:
        sum . map (\ (ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
      In an equation for ‘poly’:
          poly a b x = sum . map (\ (ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
   |
11 | poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
   |                                                                ^
```

So I already *know* what's wrong here. `a` and `b` are of type `[Int]`, but I need them to be of type `[Double]`. However, what I don't understand is why the compiler is saying what it is:

1. Why is it complaining about `b` when `a` comes before it in the expression and is equally wrong?
2. In the top-most error, the expected type is `[(Double, Double)]`. Cool, makes sense. But how come the *actual* type is `[(Int, Double)]`? How did the double emerge if both `a` and `b` are `[Int]`?

In either case, I think what I really need is someone to walk me through how the type system eventually gets to generating these errors, so I can better understand why the error messages are what they are.

Comment: The compiler just happened to figure out that `b` had a contradictory type first. This is completely arbitrary, but probably because it works backwards through function application (`f a b = (f a) b`.) As for why it doesn't complain about `a`,—why should it go further when it already knows there's a mistake?

Comment: Thanks @AJFarmar, the fact that its arbitrary is already enough justification for me. I had a feeling that was either the case or that the recursive stack was starting with `b` instead of `a`. All good. I'm still confused about why I see `[(Int, Double)]` however.

Comment: For the same reason. It probably works either forwards or backwards through the functions. `ai` is the first to be applied to in `\ (ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)`, so it only makes sense that that's the type that should be affected. Once again, this is just as arbitrary as complaining about `b`.

Comment: @AJFarmar Thanks. So, is the idea here that the compiler catches `b` first, for whatever reason, and since it has not yet gotten to `a`, it has assumed that it would be, if correct, a `Double`, not knowing that if it processed `a` it would also be wrong (because there is no reason to go any further once we find an error)?

Comment: That's exactly correct. Not only is there no good reason to continue since there's already an irreparable error, but continuing would have to take into account the two possibilities of `Int` or `Double` for that particular case, so type inference becomes twice as complex.

Comment: But it doesn't catch `b` first. It catches `zip a`. Then it keeps going and also catches `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is it complaining about `b` when a comes before it in the expression and is equally wrong?

Well, there are two errors. It complains about `zip a`, and it complains about `b`. And it issues those errors in the order they appear in the source.

> 2. In the top-most error, the expected type is `[(Double, Double)]`. Cool, makes sense. But how come the actual type is `[(Int, Double)]`? How did the double emerge if both `a` and `b` are `[Int]`?

Not so fast. The actual type in that error is not `[(Int, Double)]`. It says that `zip a` is wrong, and its says the expected type is `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]`, while the actual type is `[Double] -> [(Int, Double)]`. That's not the same thing as there being an expression which is expected to be of type `[(Double, Double)]` and actually is of type `[(Int, Double)]`.

`zip a` is a function. We know it's supposed to return `[(Double, Double)]` (because the rest of the composition chain processes that to return the final `Double` result from `poly`.

The remaining parameter of the function `zip a` needs to be of type `[Double]` (by the type of `zip`) in order for the return type to fit `[(Double, Double)]`, and that's fine; `zip a` *can* take a `[Double]` argument.

The problem is that `zip a` is not a function of type `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]`; the closest it could manage is `[Double] -> [(Int, Double)]`, because of the use of `a` in the expression `zip a`. So that's what the error complains about.

You're asking why it doesn't complain about `[(Int, Int)]` instead of `[(Int, Double)]`, since that's what you'd get if you applied `zip a` to `b`. But nowhere in your code do you do that! You apply the whole function `sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a` to `b` (via the `$` operator). The type error is not complaining about `zip a b` being the wrong type of list, it's complaining about `zip a` being the wrong type of function.

It then separately complains that the second argument of the `$` operator is *also* the wrong type to be passed as an argument to the whole function (of which `zip a` is a small part), but that's quite a separate issue from the other error.

---

What Haskell is doing during type checking is looking at every expression (including sub-expressions, at every level of nesting), and comparing:

1. The type the expression *must* have, in order to fit into its context (it calls this the "expected type")
2. The type the expression *would* have based on its components (it calls this the "actual type")

You can think of the process in this example roughly as follows:

1. `sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b` must result in `Double`, because of the type signature for `poly`
2. The first sub-expression is `$` applied to `sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a`

   1. `$` has type `(a -> b) -> a -> b` (actual type)<sup>1</sup>
   2. We know that `b` above must be `Double` by the final expected return type of `poly`, so `$` should be something of the form `(a -> Double) -> a > Double` (expected type)
   3. Expected and actual types of `$` unify with no problems
3. Now we know the expected type of `sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a` is something of the form `a -> Double`. Lets check its actual type:

   1. The first sub-expression in that composition chain is `.` applied to `sum` (`(sum .)` in operator-section notation, or `(.) sum` in prefix notation):

      1. `.` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`; its expected type in this position is something of the form `(b -> Double) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Double`
      2. `sum` has type `(Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`; its expected type in this position is something of the form `b -> Double` (needs `Num Double`:  ✔ )
      3. So `(sum .)` has type `Foldable t => (a -> t Double) -> a -> Double`
   2. The next sub-expression in the composition chain is `(sum .)` applied to `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a`

      1. `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a` is expected to fit `Foldable t => a -> t Double`. Lets check its actual type:

         1. The first sub expression of that is `.` applied to `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi))`
         2. `.` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`; its expected type in this position is something of the form `Foldable t => (b -> t Double) -> (a -> b) -> a -> t Double`
         3. So `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi))` is expected to fit `b -> t Double`
         4. Skipping over the details, `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi))` actually has type `[(Double, Double)] -> [Double]` (because `x` is known to have type `Double` from the signature of `poly`).
         5. This fits the expected type `b -> t Double`, and informs us that `b` is actually `[(Double, Double)]` and `t` is actually `[]` (needs `Foldable []`: ✔ )
      2. So now we know that the actual type of `.` applied to `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi))` is `(a -> [(Double, Double)]) -> [Double]`, which means the second argument of the `.`, which is `zip a`, is expected to be of the form `a -> [(Double, Double)]`. Lets check its actual type:

         1. `zip` is of type `[a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`
         2. `a` is of type `[Int]` from the type signature of `poly`
         3. So `zip a` has a type like `[b] -> [(Int, b)]`. Trying to unify the expected and actual type forces us to instantiate `b` to be `Double`, leaving the actual type of `zip a` being `[Double] -> [(Int, Double)]`. But now there are no more type variables to instantiate. This is the first place we've found where the actual type doesn't match the expected type. So we emit a type error. In reporting the type error, we keep the fact that `b` was instantiated to `Double`, because nothing was wrong with that. So the expected type is shown as `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]` and the actual type is shown as `[Double] -> [(Int, Double)]`
         4. There's not much point drilling down further into `zip a`, because there is no meaningful expected type for the sub-components, because **we don't know whether the issue we just reported was that the expected type is wrong or that the actual type was wrong** (we just know that they can't be both right). We cannot say whether the problem is that `zip` doesn't fit `[Int] -> [Double] -> [(Double, Double])`, or that `a` doesn't fit `[Double]`, or whether `zip a` is actually correct and the problem is that the context was expecting `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]`.
      3. But going back out and pretending that `zip a` actually did fit its expected type, we establish that `map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a` has "actual type" `[Double] -> [Double]`, which does unify with our expected type of `Foldable t => a -> t Double`
   3. And that means that `sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a` has actual type `[Double] -> Double`, which does unify with our expected type of `a -> Double` (and we now know that `a` is `Double`).
4. Which *finally* allows us to get to the next top-level expression, which is `(sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $)` applied to `b`.

   1. `b` is expected to have type `[Double]`
   2. `b` actually has type `[Int]` (by the signature for `poly`)
   3. This is our second place where actual and expected type do not match, so we report the second type error.

<sup>1</sup> But not its *actual* actual type. Saying `$` is simply a function with type `(a -> b) -> a -> b` is actually a simplification, because `$` needs to support things like unlifted types, which ordinary type variables can't support. But I'm not going to get into that here. The simplification works 99% of the time.

---

You can see that there are a huge number of steps to follow in working out how the type system generates these errors. So I don't really find that's a helpful process to follow in trying to understand type errors.

The compiler pinpoints the exact expression its talking about: both in terms of the descent of the parse tree with all those "`in the second argument of (.)`" lines, and (usually more helpfully) with the graphical indication using `^^^^` characters underneath.

So step one is to think about "why would that expression be expected to have that type", looking at the surroundings. In this case it's reasonably clear why `zip a` *should* have type `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]`; the result is feeding into mathematical operations that eventually produce `Double`, so both elements of the tuples in the list have to be `Double`, and the parameter of `zip a` must also be `[Double]`.

Step 2 is to think about "why would that expression actually have that type". Again, that's even more obvious. If `a :: [Int]`, then there's no way that `zip a` can result in something fitting `_ -> [(Double, _)]`.

The finicky details the compiler goes through to verify everything else in the context leading up to these errors is mostly irrelevant; it effectively told you that was all fine (by not emitting any type errors there).

It's also irrelevant why it discovers `zip a` first and not `b`, or why it complains about `zip a` being a function that results in `[(Int, Double)]` instead of complaining about `a` being of type `[Int]`. Fundamentally it's just going to find a place where the expected and actual type are inconsistent, without any way to tell which one is correct (often neither of them are).

These things *are* understandable, and they become reasonably intuitive as you work with the compiler for longer, but these facts very rarely actually help you understand and fix the error. Just pick the first error it reports, focus on the expression it's talking about, think about why the context would cause it to have the reported "expected type", and why the sub-parts of the expression would cause it to have the reported "actual type".

Contrary to GHC's reputation for inscrutable error messages, I actually find them to be much higher quality that those I typically get when working with other languages. When you aren't familiar with them they contain a lot of information in a new format, and so they're confusing. But once you are familiar with them they are actually very good.

In fact, this particular error message is *exactly* along the lines of the `function foo expects an argument of type int, but received string` that you were expecting! It's just that the "function foo" is the `.` operator (which you've used twice on the same line so it identifies exactly which one it's talking about) and the argument it's expecting is another function with a complex type. The only reason it looks more complicated than the type of error message you compare it to is that it splits the expected/actual part onto two lines for readability (and points out exactly which part of those two types doesn't match!) and gives you a lot of detail about exactly which sub-expression contains the error, instead of just saying `line 11: function (.) expects an argument of type [Double] -> [(Double, Double)], but received [Double] -> [(Int, Double)]`.

Comment: This is a wonderfully in-depth answer. The description of how the error may have been generated is great, but the latter half really helps with cementing my general understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it complaining about `b` when `a` comes before it in the expression and is equally wrong?

...why not? You've said yourself that they are both wrong. GHC has also figured out they are both wrong. It's telling you they are both wrong. Also, `a` doesn't really come "before", because there is no real concept of "before" and "after" in Haskell. If anything, it's "in-out", not "left-right", and then `b` (underneath only a `($)`) is "before" the `a` (underneath `zip`, `(.)`, *and* `($)`). It doesn't matter, anyway.

> In the top-most error, the expected type is `[(Double, Double)]`. Cool, makes sense. But how come the actual type is `[(Int, Double)]`? How did the double emerge if both `a` and `b` are `[Int]`?

`sum . map _etc . zip a` is expected to have type `[Int] -> Double`, because of the type signature and because it's the left side of a `($)`. Drilling deeper, `zip a` is supposed to be `[Int] -> [(Double, Double)]`. It is actually `forall b. [b] -> [(Int, b)]`. Using the argument type, we can choose to set `b ~ Int`, thereby deducing that `zip a` is actually `[Int] -> [(Int, Int)]` (which is true) where a `[Double] -> [(Double, Double)]` was expected, or we can choose to set `b ~ Double` (from the return type) and decide that, actually, `zip a :: [Double] -> [(Int, Double)]` (which is *also* true). Both ways you get an error. In fact, I think GHC is doing this in a third way, similar to the first, but I'll spare you the details.

The core of the issue is this: in a Haskell program, there are multiple ways to figure out the type of an expression if you know the types of the stuff around or in it. In a well-typed program, all these derivations agree with each other, and, in an ill-typed program, they disagree, usually in multiple ways. GHC simply chooses two of them, calls them "expected" and "actual" in a way that hopefully makes sense, and complains that they disagree. Here, you found a third derivation that is also in conflict with the "expected" derivation, but GHC, for whatever reason, chose not to use your derivation for the "actual type". Choosing which derivation to show is not easy, especially in Haskell, where everything is allowed to affect the type of everything else, though it could definitely be better. Some years ago, one of GHC's leaders did [some work](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/sherrloc-toplas.pdf) on much better error messages, but it appears to have link-rotted slightly—the Haskell-analyzer bridge seems to have link-rotted off the Internet.

If you're faced with an error like this, I would recommend, first of all, not writing in the `_ . _ . ... $ _` style. It's easier to follow my main advice if you write that as `_ $ _ $ ... $ _`. I won't change it here, but you should keep that in mind.

```
poly :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Double -> Double
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
```

You see an error and it's not immediately obvious what to change. Very well, simply give up trying to decipher the hieroglyphs and replace part(s) of the RHS with `_`. The more of the RHS you delete, the better your chance of catching the error, going to ~95% if you erase all of it:

```
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . _ $ _
-- personally, I'd nuke the scary-looking map _lambda, too,
-- but I'm also trying to keep this short
```

GHC will tell you that the left `_` is meant to be `_a -> [(Double, Double)]`, and the right one `_a`. Add the `zip`:

```
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip _ $ _
```

and you'll be told you need two `[Double]`s, and you'll realize that using `a` and `b` didn't work because `a, b :: [Int]` (and GHC actually says `a :: [Int]; b :: [Int]` in the error message, because sometimes it isn't clear). You then figure out how to fix it:

```
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip (fromIntegral <$> a) $ fromIntegral <$> b
```

All is well.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by preferring `_ $ _ $ _ $ _` over `_ . _ . _ $ _` style? I daresay the latter is rather more idiomatic Haskell style, as a general tendency.

Comment: Because `zip a b` is one conceptual unit, but you've split it into two distant parts: `(_ . (_ . zip a)) $ b`. You end up needing two `_` holes to cover the error, and even then  you get weird output like `_ :: a0 -> [(Double, Double)]`. The new `a0` variable is "glue": it's a name to show the relationship between the two holes. You use one hole and you get a nicer `_ :: [(Double, Double)]`.

Comment: @HTNW If you think of `zip a b` as one conceptual chunk, it's easy to retain that in the `_ . _ . _ $ _` style via `sum . map foo $ zip a b`. (Though of course in this case `sum $ zipWith foo a b` would be even better, and is in both styles!)

Comment: @DanielWagner But then you're back to where you started! If the error is actually in `foo`, or maybe you aren't supposed to use `map`, then the error messages devolve again. To me, the simple fact is that there is a linear structure here: `zip` `a` and `b`, then `map` `foo` over that, then `sum` it. This is reflected by `_ $ _ $ _`, while `_ . _ $ _` always introduces that artificial branch: apply (`sum` after `map foo`) to (`zip a b`).

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
poly :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Double -> Double
poly a b x = sum . map (\(ai, bi) -> ai * (x ** bi)) . zip a $ b
```

, on the one hand,

```
    a ::        [ Int]
zip a :: [t] -> [(Int,t)]
x :: Double
x ** bi :: Double
     bi :: Double
                      t ::    Double
zip a   :: [Double] -> [(Int, Double)]                     derived
```

, but on the other,

```
poly a b x          ::                      Double
sum                 ::          [Double] -> Double
    ai * (x ** bi)  ::           Double
   (ai ,       bi)  ::  (Double, Double)
zip a   :: [Double] -> [(Double, Double)]                  expected
```